# Show two activities on one screen at time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to display two Activities on one screen at time, and I suppouse the best way is using Fragments. 
The problems is I want to do something like that:

[image: example]

Initially, only will display the Activity 1, and when an event success, the Activity 2 will appear (but only the header).
Then, when the users tap on this header, the Activity 2 will go up with some kind of animation. The best aproach should be the posibility to drag the Activity 2 to the top, but initially, it's enough tapping and go up automatically.

Right now I have the two Activities implemented separately, and I want to merge on one screen.

Thanks.

Comment: This kind of stuff can easily be done with fragments. Read about fragments for now, and you'll figure that out.

Comment: Thanks PearsonArtPhoto, I need to read a little about the Fragments, and know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct of using Fragments instead of separate Activities for this is a good one. Treat the Activity like a container for these interactions.

Remember that both Activities and Fragments are lifecycle management constructs. They have some conveniences and shortcuts for *managing* UI, but they aren't Views themselves. What the user will see and interact with comes down to the Views in your window's hierarchy.

Have a look at [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) as a component that could act as a container for the content of your detail Fragment, the one you're calling "Activity 2" above. Choosing a list item could turn the SlidingDrawer components visible and populate the drawer with an appropriate detail Fragment's content.

Comment: Good  suggestion to use SlidingDrawer, but right now the Activity 2 have near 1000 code lines, and the Activity 1 over 500, and if I'm not wrong, I need to merge the code to use the SlidingDrawer, and I think is not a good idea. By the way, the Activity 2 is called from other parts of the App.. I think I should use Fragments. I will looking for some examples. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing about the SlidingDrawer. I see that is deprecated on API Level 17. Not good idea to use it right now. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The SlidingDrawer would become a container for views managed by one of your fragments. Using a SlidingDrawer is not mutually exclusive with using fragments for code organization. This doesn't involve merging activity code. Also, while it is indeed deprecated, that simply means it won't be receiving new features or updates and there are probably other UX patterns you should look into, even though what it does is more or less what you described that you want. It's not going to be removed from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use bottom to top animation, when switching activities.. just create animation.. and when user click on header override animation of activity.. thats all

Comment: Henrik, good approach, In fact is the current implementation, I have a bottom to top animation, but i want to create the effect that the header goes up. Now I show a RelativeLayout simulating a header, and when the users tap on it, the new activity goes up, but over the RelativeLayout. Thanks for your time :)